# Set RowTemplate DividerHeight in DataGridView when using AutoSizeRowsMode

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView in a WinForms project with the AutoSizeRowsMode set to "AllCells".  I would like to increase the space between rows, but setting the DividerHeight in the RowTemplate has no effect.  Does anyone know how to increase the space between rows when the AutoSizeRowsMode is a value other than "None"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was able to get this like I wanted by setting the padding on the DefaultCellStyle.